# Firebase Dynamic URL work on offline?

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

I just integrated Firebase dynamic link. It is not working offline. So, Just i wanted to confirm, is it true firebase dynamic link requires Internet?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you want to create a deeplink without shorten the url, you can do it in **offline**.

If you need to shorten the url then it needs to be **online**.